# How to let an existing user buy a subscription without signing in?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-research, usability-testing, checkout

1. How can an existing user continue buying a subscription using the
   same email ID without signing in?

   I have made the new user to create a password at the end of the
   checkout/purchasing the subscription. I want even existing users
   finish the checkout without signing in/verifying the email ID.
   Later, they should be able to access the subscription with that
   email ID.

   Why? Because, there's a chance that they might forget the password
   which may result in drop-off's
2. What if user enter wrong email ID during checkout? How can he get
   his subscription back into his account?

Comment: 1. "Reset my password" link. 2. Use "confirm email address" pattern during sign-up. If they get it wrong twice... tough luck

Comment: @musefan letting users to reset their password will divert them from the checkout. This should be avoided.

Comment: If you have a requirement to link the subscription to their account then they **have** to log in, there is no workaround for that. Just force them to log in.

Comment: What if another person use your email ID as he need not know password - specially or by mistake? You will charge for this unauthorised purchase?

Comment: @Serg 1. Yes, definitely I'll charge for it. He completed the payment without verifying his email ID. That was his mistake. But, he still can get his subscription back to his proper email ID using customer support.

2. A subscription verification link will be sent to the email address. Only after confirming, the user can access it.